# Unable to print character value received on serial port in Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am trying to receive char from serial port and print it on command window of Matlab. For this I write this code:-

```
serialOne=serial('COM6', 'BaudRate', 19200);
fopen(serialOne);
while 1>0
recv = fread(serialOne, 1 ,'uint8');
recv
end
fclose(serialOne);
```

To test this application I am actually sending some data from teraterm and trying to receive it correctly in matlab.

And my output is this:-

On sending char '1' from Teraterm  I should receive char '1' on Matlab but:-

```
recv =

     49
```

On sending char '2' from Teraterm  I should receive char '2' on Matlab but:-

```
recv =

    50
```

I observed that I am receiving ASCII (in decimal) for every character  that I am sending from terminal. So my question is how do I get the characters directly instead of the decimal ASCII  values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fread` function returns the character as number, i.e. the ASCII code. To convert it to the `char` type, you can use `recv = char(recv)` after receiving the character.

Another possibility would be to use `recv = fscanf(serialOne,'%c',1)` which will return one character directly in the `char` type.

Comment: replacing uint8 by char make no difference, But I got ans. I have to convert it into char by this function:- char(recv)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. I assumed it would work, but couldn't test it. I'll change my answer accordingly.